# How to build a project through CMakeLists mother?

Tags: c++, cmake

Suppose my project has several sub-modules, and the architecture is:

- **/CMakeLists.txt** (*Base*) -> Call subdirectory
- **/projectName/CMakeLists.txt** (*Child*) -> Call subdirectory moduleName and add main project sources
- **/projectName/xxx.cpp**
- **/projectName/moduleName/CMakeLists.txt** (Child of Child) -> Add the module sources
- **/projectName/moduleName/xxx.cpp**

I could just do with a single CMakeLists adding many sources, but I think the CMake has been made ​​to work this way.

My CMakeLists.txt:

**Main CMakeLists.txt:**

```
# CMake Minimum Version Required ( >= 2.8 )
cmake_minimum_required ( VERSION 2.8 )

# CMake Project Name and Languages
project ( LightUpdater C CXX )

# Add Compiler Definitions
add_definitions ( -Wall -Werror )

# Include source headers
include_directories ( lightupdater )

# Add custom module folder
set( CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/CMakeModules;${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}" )
set ( EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR} ) # Binary output folder

# Setup project variables
set ( LIGHTUPDATER_OUTPUT lightupdater )
set ( LIGHTUPDATER_SOURCES "" )

# Add Source Subdirectory
add_subdirectory ( lightupdater )
```

**/projectName/CMakeLists.txt**

```
# Setup the source code files
list ( APPEND LIGHTUPDATER_SOURCES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lightupdater.cpp )

# Add Modules
add_subdirectory ( interface )
```

**/projectName/moduleName/CMakeLists.txt**

```
list ( APPEND LIGHTUPDATER_SOURCES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/gui.cpp )

# Qt4
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Find Qt4 (REQUIRED)
find_package( Qt4 REQUIRED )
# Compiler setup
include ( ${QT_USE_FILE} )
add_definitions ( ${QT_DEFINITIONS} )
include_directories( ${QT_INCLUDE_DIR} )

# Setup the interface sources
set( INTERFACE_HEADER ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/gui.hpp )

# Process headers
QT4_WRAP_CPP( INTERFACE_HEADER_MOC ${INTERFACE_HEADER} )
list( APPEND LIGHTUPDATER_SOURCES ${INTERFACE_HEADER_MOC} )
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Define Qt Operating System
# Created by Renato Utsch
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
set( GUI_TYPE "" )
if( APPLE )
    set( GUI_TYPE MACOSX_BUNDLE )
elseif( WIN32 )
    set( GUI_TYPE WIN32 )
endif()

# Compiler call
add_executable( ${LIGHTUPDATER_OUTPUT} ${GUI_TYPE} ${LIGHTUPDATER_SOURCES} )
# Linking the 3rd party librarys
target_link_libraries( ${LIGHTUPDATER_OUTPUT} ${QT_LIBRARIES} )
```

I want the calling process to occur in the compiler CMakeLists.txt mother, and not in the module as it is today.

Answer (score 0):

So, you just want all your CMake code to reside in root CMakeLists.txt? No problem.

In root CMakeLists.txt substitute `add_subdirectory()` with `projectName/CMakeLists.txt` and replace `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lightupdater.cpp` with `lightupdater/lightupdater.cpp`.

Finally, rewrite `/projectName/moduleName/CMakeLists.txt` the same way.

Comment: Replace all uses of `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}` with explicit path.

Comment: But I need define the source in the modules path, and recover the variables back again to the root CMakeLists.txt and compile.

Comment: Uhm. I didn't get what you want then. May be PARENT_SCOPE or CACHE specifiers in set() command would help you.

Comment: But after I add a sub_directory, the CMake don't return to the Main CMakeLists

Comment: Put the SOURCE var in the child CMakeLists.txt don't return

Comment: But you are going to move everything into single root CMakeLists.txt, aren't you? Anyway, use `set(SOURCE "asdasd" PARENT_SCOPE)`